# PostgreSQL join tables on data range

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

in PostreSQL, I'm currently trying to join the following tables:

| ID | From | To | Color | Shape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 10:05:31.510 | 2021-09-13 16:40:27.000 | Red |  |
| 1 | 2021-09-13 16:40:27.000 | 2022-07-01 14:34:53.728 | Red | Square |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 14:34:53.728 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000 | Red | Circle |

| ID | From | Letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 | A |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00.000 | B |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00.000 | C |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00.000 | D |

The second table doesn't have a valid to, the record is valid until a new one with a greater From is inserted.

The expected output is this table:

| ID | From | To | Color | Shape | Letter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 10:05:31.510 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 | Red |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-09-13 16:40:27.000 | Red |  | A |
| 1 | 2021-09-13 16:40:27.000 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00.000 | Red | Square | A |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 14:34:53.728 | Red | Square | B |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 14:34:53.728 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00.000 | Blue | Circle | B |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00.000 | Green | Circle | C |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000 | Green | Circle | D |

I tried with a full join on the IDs and b.From between a.From and a.To, but I wasn't able to fix the new records From and To dates.

Any input is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use left join and the lead function to get your expected output.

```
WITH CombinedTable AS (
  SELECT a.ID, a."From" AS a_From, a."To" AS a_To, a.Color, a.Shape, b."From" AS b_From, b.Letter,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID, a."From" ORDER BY b."From") AS rn
  FROM TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b."From" >= a."From" AND b."From" <= a."To"
)
SELECT ID, a_From AS "From", 
       LEAD(a_From) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY a_From) AS "To",
       Color, Shape, Letter
FROM CombinedTable
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to simply copy and paste your query but I didn't quite get the expected result.
https://imgur.com/a/3gxVGsp

(Let me know if there is a better way to share the result, first time posting)

Comment: I have modified the code now and I think it should work properly now

Comment: No it's not. May i please ask to test on your own before publishing an answer? Thanks!